# How to Merge data of multiple rows into Single row SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have multiple rows for each customer and I want to merge data into single row. How we can achieve this in SQL.

Source:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Comment: Please explain the logic for choosing among the columns, particularly those with multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  Something like this would work on your sample data:

```
select customerid, firstname, min(channelcode),
       max(case when email like '%@%' then email end) as email,
       max(case when email not like '%@%' then email end) as mobile,
       min(addressline1), ...
from t
group by customerid, firstname;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the row values are dependent on the Channelcode column.  To be guaranteed the query will return 1 row per CustomerId the GROUP BY consists of only CustomerId.  Something like this

```
select CustomerId, max(FirstName) FirstName, max(DateOfBirth) DateOfBirth, 
       max(case when Channelcode='EML' then Channelcode else null end) Channelcode,
       max(case when Channelcode='EML' then email else null end) email,
       max(case when Channelcode='MBL' then email else null end) Mobile,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then AddressLine1 else null end) AddressLine1,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then AddressLine2 else null end) AddressLine2,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then AddressLine3 else null end) AddressLine3,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then Suburb null end) Suburb,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then Postcode else null end) Postcode,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then statecode else null end) statecode,
       max(case when Channelcode='POS' then countrycode else null end) countrycode
from MultiRows
group by CustomerId;
```

Comment: Perfect, I had a similar issue trying to remove a 0 from a duplicate row, this did the trick.